# How to save plots that are made in a shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to figure out how to use downloadButton to save a plot with shiny. The example in the package demonstrates `downloadButton/downloadHandler` to save a .csv. I'm going to make a reproducible example based on that.

For `ui.R`

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Downloading Data'),
  sidebarPanel(
selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
            choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data'),
    downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download Plot')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot')
  )
))
```

For `server.R`

```
library(ggplot2)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })
  
  plotInput <- reactive({
    df <- datasetInput()
    p <-ggplot(df, aes_string(x=names(df)[1], y=names(df)[2])) +
      geom_point()
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    print(plotInput())
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datatasetInput(), file)
    }
  )
  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.png', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(file,plotInput())
    }
  )
})
```

If you're answering this question, you are probably familiar with this, but to get this working, save the above into separate scripts (`ui.R` and `server.R` into a folder (`foo`) within the working directory. To run the shiny app, run `runApp("foo")`.

Using `ggsave`, I get an error message indicating that `ggsave` can't use the `filename` function (I think). If I use the standard graphics device (like below), the `Download Plot` works without an error, but it doesn't write the graphic.

Any tips to get downloadHandler working for writing plots would be appreciated.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Not sure if this question is still active but it's the first one that came up when searching for "saving plots in shiny app" so I wanted to quickly add how to get ggsave to work with downloadHandler along the lines of the original question.

The alternative strategies suggested by juba using direct output instead of ggsave and alternative strategy suggested by alexwhan himself both work great, this is just for those who absolutely want to use ggsave in the downloadHandler).

The problem reported by alexwhan is caused by ggsave trying to match the file extension to the correct graphics device. The temporary file, however, doesn't have an extension so the matching fails. This can be remedied by specifically setting the device in the `ggsave` function call, like so in the original code example (for a png):

```
output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.png', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
        device <- function(..., width, height) grDevices::png(..., width = width, height = height, res = 300, units = "in")
        ggsave(file, plot = plotInput(), device = device)
    }
)
```

This call basically takes the `device` function for a `png` that `ggsave` assigns internally (you can look at the `ggsave` function code to see the syntax for `jpg`, `pdf`, etc). Perhaps, ideally, one could specify the file extension (if different from the file name - as is the case here for the temporary file) as a `ggsave` parameter but this option is currently not available in `ggsave`.

---

A minimal self-contained working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(downloadButton('foo')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    plotInput = function() {
      qplot(speed, dist, data = cars)
    }
    output$foo = downloadHandler(
      filename = 'test.png',
      content = function(file) {
        device <- function(..., width, height) {
          grDevices::png(..., width = width, height = height,
                         res = 300, units = "in")
        }
        ggsave(file, plot = plotInput(), device = device)
      })
  }
))

sessionInfo()
# R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# 
# locale:
#  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
#  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
# [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] ggplot2_1.0.0 shiny_0.10.1 
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] bitops_1.0-6     caTools_1.17     colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4    
#  [5] formatR_1.0      grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.1.2     htmltools_0.2.6 
#  [9] httpuv_1.3.0     labeling_0.2     MASS_7.3-34      munsell_0.4.2   
# [13] plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2      reshape2_1.4    
# [17] RJSONIO_1.3-0    scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1     
# [21] xtable_1.7-3
```

## Update

As of ggplot2 version 2.0.0, the `ggsave` function supports character input for the `device` parameter, that means the temporary file created by the downloadHandler can now be saved with a direct call to `ggsave` by specifying that the extension to be used should be e.g. `"pdf"` (rather than passing in a device function). This simplifies the above example to the following

```
output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.png', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
        ggsave(file, plot = plotInput(), device = "png")
    }
)
```

Comment: I believe your answer is actually the correct one here. You can also just use `ggsave(file, plotInput(), device = png)` instead of creating a device (wrapper) function.

Comment: @sebkopf I missed your answer in the intervening year and a bit!

Comment: @Yihui This solution doesn't work for me: R version 3.1.0, ggplot2_1.0.0 shiny_0.10.1. Save box pops up, click save, but no file is saved. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @zx8754 I just added a full example to the answer. Note you should run it in your web browser instead of viewing it in RStudio, since the RStudio viewer has a known bug of being unable to download files.

Comment: @Yihui Thanks, yes I was running it on RStudio viewer... Ah!

Comment: @Yihui Thanks for adding the full example. You probably found this already but just for clarification: the device wrapper function is required because the parameters passed by ggsave are not always compatible with the device defaults (e.g. for the ```png``` function's ```units``` parameter the default is "px"). For a general solution to this question, there's a [pull request](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/939#issuecomment-39807370) for a feature that would allow ```ggsave(... device="png")``` as an easy way to have ```ggsave``` specifically pick its own png wrapper.

Comment: @sebkopf Yes, I realized it after I tried a real example, so my first comment here was actually wrong. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Typo: In the update it should say "output$foo" instead of "output$downloadPlot", shouldn't it?

Answer (score 27):

This is old, but still the top hit when someone googles "R shiny save ggplot", so I will contribute another workaround. Very simple... call ggsave in the same function that displays your graph, which will save the graph as a file on the server.

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggsave("plot.pdf", plotInput())
    plotInput()
})
```

Then, use downloadHandler and use `file.copy()` to write data from the existing file to the "file" parameter.

```
output$dndPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
        "plot.pdf"
    },
    content = function(file) {
        file.copy("plot.pdf", file, overwrite=TRUE)
    }
)
```

Works for me.

Comment: This was the best solution for me - thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I didn't manage to make it work with `ggsave`, but with a standard call to `png()` it seems to be okay.

I only changed the `output$downloadPlot` part of your `server.R` file :

```
 output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '.png', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      png(file)
      print(plotInput())
      dev.off()
    })
```

Note that I had some problems with the 0.3 version of shiny, but it works with the latest from Github :

```
library(devtools)
install_github("shiny","rstudio")
```

Comment: OK, I'm going to accept that ggsave isn't going to work at this stage of proceedings with downloadHandler. shiny 0.3 falls apart with downloadHandler, you're right. I'll post an alternative solution I figured out avoiding downloadHandler which will allow ggsave to work.

Comment: @juba any idea why [this attempt to output to pdf](https://gist.github.com/geotheory/b0c36071b7c0c2b384db) with a similar (non-ggplot2) method doesn't work? I just get a broken pdf that doesn't open. Can plotInput not deliver a plot instead of a plot object?

Answer (score 24):

Here's a solution that allows using ggsave for saving shiny plots. It uses a logical checkbox and text input to call `ggsave()`. Add this to the `ui.R` file inside `sidebarPanel`:

```
textInput('filename', "Filename"),
checkboxInput('savePlot', "Check to save")
```

Then add this to the `server.R` file instead of the current `output$plot` reactivePlot function:

```
output$plot <- reactivePlot(function() {
    name <- paste0(input$filename, ".png")
    if(input$savePlot) {
      ggsave(name, plotInput(), type="cairo-png")
    }
    else print(plotInput())
  })
```

A user can then type the desired filename in the textbox (without extension) and tick the checkbox to save in the app directory. Unchecking the box prints the plot again. I'm sure there are neater ways of doing this, but at least I can now use ggsave and cairo in windows for much nicer png graphics.

Please add any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Without an `isolate` block around the `input$filename`, any change to the `filename` text box will also prompt a file save if the box is checked.