# Shiny-server, openxlsx plots not able to be inserted

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

When running the following shiny app from the console with runApp(), it works as expected, displaying a plot and providing the ability to download an excel file with the plot embedded. Running the same app on shiny-server, yields the error

> cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'

- Shiny Server v1.4.2.786
- Node.js v0.10.40
- R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

  ```
  library(shiny)
  library(openxlsx)
  library(magrittr)

  # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
  ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

     # Application title
     titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

     # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
     sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
           sliderInput("bins",
                       "Number of bins:",
                       min = 1,
                       max = 50,
                       value = 30),
           downloadButton('specDataDownload',
                          label = "Download",
                          class = NULL)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
     )
  ))

  # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

     output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- isolate({faithful[, 2] })
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

     })
     output$specDataDownload <- downloadHandler(
         filename = function() {
             paste("ProcessedPlateAssay",
                   gsub("-|[[:space:]]|:",
                        "",
                        Sys.time()),
                   ".xlsx",
                   sep = "_")
         },
         content = function(con) {
             x    <- isolate({faithful[, 2] })
             bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
             output <- createWorkbook()
             addWorksheet(
                 output,
                 "One")
             hist(
                 x,
                 breaks = bins,
                 col = 'darkgray',
                 border = 'white')
             insertPlot(
                 output,
                 sheet = 1,
                 startRow = (1),
                 startCol = 5,
                 width = 6.5,
                 height = 3,
                 fileType = "png",
                 units = "in",
                 dpi = 600)

         saveWorkbook(
             wb = output,
             file = con
         )
         })
  })

  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  ```

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Here's how we solved it: (1) use jpeg to open a (temporary) plot; (2) execute your plot command, (3) close the jpeg, use insertImage.

Comment: Hi, I ultimately solved that aspect as well but the underlying issue was that the shiny user on my server didn't have write permission to the folder (it was created as a git repository and pushed to the server).

Answer (score 5):

I thought to provide a minimal example since I have struggled with the issue of `openxlsx`'s `insertPlot` function not working inside shiny-server, probably due to permission issues with `tempfile` or `dev.copy`. The method that worked best for me was to use `ggsave`, since it handles resolution very neatly, and also has a scale parameter which allows resizing of the image elements making it more suitable for a presentation. I have also included a second method using the `png` function.

Below is a reproducible example, partly drawn from the answer by @sebkopf in [Save plots made in a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810409/save-plots-made-in-a-shiny-app])

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink("downloadExcel", "Excel Graph Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  p1 <- qplot(mpg, data=mtcars, geom="density", fill=as.factor(gear), 
alpha=I(.5), main="Distribution of Gas Mileage")
  p2 <- qplot(age, circumference, data = Orange, geom = c("point", "line"), 
colour = Tree)

  output$downloadExcel <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "savePlot.xlsx",
    content = function(file){
      wb <- createWorkbook()

      addWorksheet(wb, "ggsave", gridLines = F)
      addWorksheet(wb, "png", gridLines = F)

      # Method 1: using ggsave

      ggsave("p1.png", plot = p1, scale = .6) # Scale parameter resizes the object making text more legible
      ggsave("p2.png", plot = p2, scale = .6)

      insertImage(wb, "ggsave", "p1.png", width = 5, height = 3.5)
      insertImage(wb, "ggsave", "p22.png", startCol = "J", width = 16, height = 10, units = "cm")

      # Method 2: using png function

      png("p11.png")
      print(p1)
      dev.off()

      insertImage(wb, "png", "p11.png", width = 5, height = 3.5)

      png("p22.png")
      print(p2)
      dev.off()

      insertImage(wb, "png", "p22.png", startCol = "J", width = 16, height = 10, units = "cm")

      saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = T)

      unlink(c("p1", "p2", "p11", "p22")) # To remove the images from the server
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: And remember to check if shiny is the owner of the directory you are trying to write into: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/srWETT6uL-I through `sudo chown shiny:shiny /var/shiny-server/www/shiny_test/work`

Comment: I needed a `tempdir()` to make it work. e.g. in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983222/putting-images-into-xlsx-docs-through-shiny-on-shiny-server -- I suppose this could be done instead of `chown`.