# Putting images into xlsx docs through Shiny on shiny-server

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, xlsx, shiny-server

I believe I'm running into permission issues between a working shiny app running though RStudio on my laptop and shiny-server on ubuntu.

This sample app for instance will write an image in an xlsx doc and let you download the xlsx.  It will work in rstudio running shiny locally but not through shiny-server.  I'm guessing that there is a way to write the png in a secure way temporarily and call it back for writing to the xlsx that is kosher with shiny-server.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny);library(openxlsx);library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.xlsx",
    content = function(file){
      wb <- createWorkbook(paste0(Sys.time(), ".xlsx"))
      my_plot <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_line(aes(x = cyl, y = gear))
      worksheet_name <- "ggplot"

      addWorksheet(wb, worksheet_name)
      png("plot.png", width=1024, height=768, units="px", res=144)
      print(my_plot)
      dev.off()  
      insertImage(wb, worksheet_name, "plot.png", width=11.18, height=7.82, units="in")

      saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
    })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(),
      downloadButton('downloadReport')),
    mainPanel()
  ))
)
```

Comment: Do you get any error message? You can use tempdir() to get a save place for storing the temporary image.

Comment: thanks. tempdir is how I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the hint from ralf-stubner, I changed

```
png("plot.png", width=1024, height=768, units="px", res=144)
```

to

```
png(paste0(tempdir(), "/", "plot.png"), width=1024, height=768, units="px", res=144)
```

and

```
insertImage(wb, worksheet_name, "plot.png", width=11.18, height=7.82, units="in")
```

to

```
insertImage(wb, worksheet_name, paste0(tempdir(), "/", "plot.png"), width=11.18, height=7.82, units="in")
```

and now the image is written to a temporary directory with the right permissions instead of the app directory, which only worked on my local development laptop.