# Getting image from data uri

Tags: r, image, web-scraping, decode, data-uri

I'm trying to scrap data and one of the data is also the image, which is embeded in data uri. I can't figure it out hot to do this with r.

```
library(rvest)
webUrl<-"https://portaltramites.inpi.gob.ar/Marcas/Logo?Acta=3363531"

imgscr<- read_html(webUrl) %>%
html_node(xpath = '//*/img') %>%
html_attr('src')

img<-gsub("data:image/gif;base64,","",imgsrc, fixed=true)

head(img)

#now I'm stuck
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(openssl)
library(magick)

pg <- read_html("https://portaltramites.inpi.gob.ar/Marcas/Logo?Acta=3363531")

img <- html_nodes(pg, "img")

img_src <- html_attr(img, "src")
img_src <- gsub("^data.*base64,", "", img_src)

image_read(base64_decode(img_src))
```

You can then use other `magick` package functions to save/manipulate/etc.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.