# Extract all click event plots from Shiny, Plotly - R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

In the following `shiny` app, the `plotly` package is used to create an interactive correlation heat map. When individual tiles are clicked, the corresponding scatter plot appears. One can then download the individual scatters by clicking `download plot as png`. But is there a way to download all the possible scatter plots at once without having to click each individual tile and save each individual one? Thank you

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

# compute a correlation matrix
correlation <- round(cor(mtcars), 3)
nms <- names(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("heat"),
    plotlyOutput("scatterplot")
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("selection")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$heat <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x = nms, y = nms, z = correlation, 
            key = correlation, type = "heatmap", source = "heatplot") %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = ""), 
             yaxis = list(title = ""))
  })

  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (length(s) == 0) {
      "Click on a cell in the heatmap to display a scatterplot"
    } else {
      cat("You selected: \n\n")
      as.list(s)
    }
  })

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlotly({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "heatplot")
    if (length(s)) {
      vars <- c(s[["x"]], s[["y"]])
      d <- setNames(mtcars[vars], c("x", "y"))
      yhat <- fitted(lm(y ~ x, data = d))
      plot_ly(d, x = ~x) %>%
        add_markers(y = ~y) %>%
        add_lines(y = ~yhat) %>%
        layout(xaxis = list(title = s[["x"]]), 
               yaxis = list(title = s[["y"]]), 
               showlegend = FALSE)
    } else {
      plotly_empty()
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does it need to run only locally or in the browser?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters The app runs in the browser, but the scatter plots are saved as png files locally.

Comment: You don't have to do it with plotly. You could use a loop that would produce all the plots you want and you can download them with an `actionButton` or `download` button.

Comment: @MLavoie I’m intrigued. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: here is an [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177129/ggplot-and-loops) of what I had in mind. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810409/save-plots-made-in-a-shiny-app) could download the plots. It is not easy but it might be possible :-)

Comment: Is it possible that the 2nd graph appears only after the click event in heatmap and uses the data from the heatmap to plot another graph?(Only appearing after the click in heatmap)? @MLavoie

Answer (score 4):

You can use `webshot` to capture a static image of Plotly's HTML output using the instructions here: https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/

An example for loop below generates random scatter plots from `mtcars`.

```
library(plotly)
library(webshot)

## You'll need to run the function the first time if you dont't have phantomjs installed
#webshot::install_phantomjs()
ColumnOptions <- colnames(mtcars)

for (i in seq_len(5)){
  xCol <- sample(ColumnOptions,1)
  yCol <- sample(ColumnOptions,1)
  ThisFileName <- paste0("Scatter_",xCol,"_vs_",yCol,".png")

  plot_ly(x = mtcars[[xCol]], y = mtcars[[yCol]], type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% 
    export(., file = ThisFileName)
}
```

However, if you're going to be potentially doing this dozens of times, the amount of computation required to go through the following steps really adds up.

1. Generate a JSON `plotly` object from `R`
2. Use `htmlwidgets`/`htmltools`to generate a self-contained HTML web page
3. Render that HTML as a browser would see it with an external program --`webshot`
4. Use `webshot` to render an image of that HTML and save it as a PNG

This isn't really a reflection of `plotly` being slow, but to make an analogy it's kind've like using an airplane to travel half a mile -- the plane gets you there, but if you need to make that trip more than a few times you should probably consider a car.

The `plotly` loop above takes 27 seconds to render 5 PNG images, but the alternative method below using `ggplot2` takes 1.2 seconds.

```
library(ggplot2)

ColumnOptions <- colnames(mtcars)

for (i in seq_len(5)){
  xCol <- sample(ColumnOptions,1)
  yCol <- sample(ColumnOptions,1)
  ThisFileName <- paste0("ggplot2_Scatter_",xCol,"_vs_",yCol,".png")

  ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = mtcars[[xCol]], y = mtcars[[yCol]])) +
    labs(x = xCol, y = yCol) -> ThisPlot 

  ggsave(plot = ThisPlot, filename = ThisFileName)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this info. However, I'm not sure it answers my question. This involves running separate scripts outside of the shiny app and also deals with the scatter plots alone. The example script provides a heat map first, with each scatter plot linked to a tile. I am looking for a way to quickly get each scatter plot that is linked to each tile. I hope that makes sense.