# Issue creating a Shiny App: Input data+ plot specs (in csv) and Save Plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am unable to create a Shiny App that:

1. Takes as input: datafiles and plot specifications in csv file format.
2. When pressing action button: runs all plots and saves them in a pre-specified folder (mentioned in the plot spec file) in a computer.
3. While plots are running, I would like to display just the progress bar to the user.

Can someone kindly guide on Shiny app structure.

PS: Apologize for posting a conceptual query and not sharing any specific codes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should learn about shiny with [written tutorials](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/) from the official website. Then, you could use some tricks from [advanced-shiny](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny#readme).

- 1) to upload a file you can check widget gallery from official shiny website [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html)
- 2) You can check this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810409/save-plots-made-in-a-shiny-app)
- 3) you can check this [code](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/plot-spinner) to show a wheel when loading, it will be a good start

Hope it helps to start!