# R Shiny saving reactive ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to figure out how to save reactive ggplots in my R Shiny project. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810409/save-plots-made-in-a-shiny-app) guide as well as the guide on the R Shiny website. However, I think I may be having an issue since I'm using reactive plots.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(uiOutput('topbox')),
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(
          id = 'tabset1',
          width = '100%',
          tabPanel('Grades Graph', downloadButton('Download'), plotOutput('individualGraph')),
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  grades <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    inFile <- input$file
    if (endsWith(inFile$name, '.xlsx')){
      gradesTbl <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
      gradesTbl <- gradesTbl %>% 
        arrange(Period, Student, Date, Type) %>% 
        mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
      return(gradesTbl)
    } else if (endsWith(inFile$name, 'csv')){
      gradesTbl <- read_csv(inFile$datapath)
      gradesTbl <- gradesTbl %>% 
        arrange(Period, Student, Date, Type) %>% 
        mutate(Date = mdy(Date))
      return(gradesTbl)
    }
  })

  output$Download <- downloadHandler(
   filename = function(){
     paste('test', '.png', sep = '')
   },
   content = function(file){
     ggsave(file, plot = output$individualGraph, device = 'png')
   }
  )

  indivdf <- function(){
    data.frame(grades()) %>%
      filter((Student == input$studentVar) & (Period == input$periodVar) & (Type %in% input$typeVar) & (Unit %in% input$unitVar))
  }

  output$individualGraph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$periodVar)
    indivdf() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Grade,
                 color = Type, shape = Unit)) +
      geom_point(size = 4) +
      ggtitle(paste(input$studentVar, "'s Individual Grades", sep = '')) +
      plotTheme() +
      scale_shape_manual(values = 1:10) +
      facet_wrap(Unit~.) +
      scale_color_manual(values = c('#E51A1D', '#377DB9', '#4EAE4A'))
  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/thomaskellough/4a5ec5861d552cc16a0b5bb17319fbab), but I think this is everything to show what I'm trying to do. I just can't figure out how to save these tables and plots that are reactive. I feel like it's something to do with using 'plot = output$indididualGraph', but I truly don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to take the code to generate the plot and move it from the `renderPlot` into a `reactive`. 
Then you can call the same `reactive` from inside a `renderPlot` to display the graph in the UI and from your `downloadHandler` to download the plot.

See the example below. 
Using the same variable name for the reactive (`individualGraph()`) and the output return (`output$individualGraph`) may not be the best coding practise but I find it more convenient.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    individualGraph <- reactive({
        req(input$periodVar)
        indivdf() %>%
            ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Grade,
                       color = Type, shape = Unit)) +
            geom_point(size = 4) +
            ggtitle(paste(input$studentVar, "'s Individual Grades", sep = '')) +
            plotTheme() +
            scale_shape_manual(values = 1:10) +
            facet_wrap(Unit~.) +
            scale_color_manual(values = c('#E51A1D', '#377DB9', '#4EAE4A'))
    })

    output$individualGraph <- renderPlot({
        req(individualGraph())
        individualGraph()
    })

    output$Download <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function(){
            paste('test', '.png', sep = '')
        },
        content = function(file){
            req(individualGraph())
            ggsave(file, plot = individualGraph(), device = 'png')
        }
    )

    grades <- reactive({
        req(input$file)
        inFile <- input$file
        if (endsWith(inFile$name, '.xlsx')){
            gradesTbl <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
            gradesTbl <- gradesTbl %>% 
                arrange(Period, Student, Date, Type) %>% 
                mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
            return(gradesTbl)
        } else if (endsWith(inFile$name, 'csv')){
            gradesTbl <- read_csv(inFile$datapath)
            gradesTbl <- gradesTbl %>% 
                arrange(Period, Student, Date, Type) %>% 
                mutate(Date = mdy(Date))
            return(gradesTbl)
        }
    })

    indivdf <- function(){
        data.frame(grades()) %>%
            filter((Student == input$studentVar) & (Period == input$periodVar) & (Type %in% input$typeVar) & (Unit %in% input$unitVar))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. Sorry it took me so long to reply. I ran into some issues getting the filename to work. After a lot of trial and error, I found it only works when I run it in my browser, but not running it in R Studio itself. Thanks again for the solution!