# Saving user generated ggplot from Shiny App

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny Web App with a ggplot and include a feature to download the generated plot. Here are my UI and Server files respectively.

SERVER

```r
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  
    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
      gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
      vals$gg <- gg
      
      print(gg)
    }, height = function() {
      session$clientData$output_BehPlot_width
    } )
    
    # downloadHandler contains 2 arguments as functions, namely filename, content
    output$down <- downloadHandler(
      filename =  function() {
        paste("behavior", input$var3, sep=".")
      },
      # content is a function with argument file. content writes the plot to the device
      content = function(filename) {
        if(input$var3 == "png"){
          png(filename) # open the png device
          #ggsave(vals$gg)
          print(vals$gg) # for GGPLOT
          dev.off()  # turn the device off
          }
        else {
          #ggsave(vals$gg)
          pdf(filename) # open the pdf device
        print(vals$gg) # for GGPLOT
        dev.off()  # turn the device off
        }
      } 
    )


    
})
```

UI

```r
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("TEST SHINY"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId = "var3", label = "Select the file type", choices = list("png", "pdf")),
      
      downloadButton("downloadPlot", "Download")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("Plot", height="auto", width = "auto")
    )
  )
))
```

This is built from the consultation of several prior Stack Overflow threads and Github gists. (such as this one: [R Shiny saving reactive ggplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029794/r-shiny-saving-reactive-ggplots))

When I run the download feature in a test session in my R console and browser, the result is an HTML file that does not print the plot. Is there something that I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be `downloadButton("down", "Download")` instead of `downloadPlot`. Additionally it should be `session$clientData$output_Plot_width` instead of `output_BehPlot_width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plotly` package to do this. As a bonus your plot will be interactive. To save plot look at the top right icon menu drawn by plotly.

```
library(plotly)

# use plotlyOutput instead of plotOutput in UI
# use renderPlotly instead of renderPlot in server
# wrap your ggplot in ggplotly

output$Plot <- renderPlotly(
  ggplotly(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point())
)
```

Note: in your code you don't have to put your plot in a reactive variable as it will not trigger an observer or a renderer. A simple variable will do the job.